# Is there a way to provide certificate information "on the fly" to a Java application?

Tags: java, ssl, client-certificates

I'll start out by saying that security certificates in general are still pretty much a black box to me.

I'm writing a simple Spring Boot Java application that is attempting to access a REST service. I believe I have the plumbing set up correctly, but am running into a security issue related to certificates (or maybe lack thereof). When I execute my call, I get an exception that boils down to the following:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have searched the web, including SO and found tons of posts and responses. From what I can tell, the predominant solution is that I need to add the cert of the site I'm attempting to access to the Java keystore via the `keytool` utility that is part of the JRE. The exact process to follow (up to date for any changes in the tool and the cert data files themselves) is a little unclear. (If anyone can point to an up-to-date process that would be great.)

What I really would like to know is: Is there an alternative to the solution mentioned? Is there a way to provide the certificate information to the Java application "on the fly" without having to store it in the Java keystore?

Comment: You would have to get and provide that certificate information in any case so there's not much difference from adding it to the keystore to providing it "on the fly". If you want to distribute your application it could bring its own keystore and point Java to it in the JVM parameters. How do add a certificate to the keystore depends on the Java version though, e.g. there was a change from Java 7 to 8 and I'm not sure there were others after that. So what Java version are you using?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to add the site's certificate to the keystore. You could add the intermediate or root certificate as well which might help with other sites too. It's basically a chain of certificates which are used to sign and verify other certificates so if you trust one cert (by adding it to keystore) then all certs certified with it directly or indirectly are trusted as well. More info can be found here (also how to add the cert): https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/how-to-import-public-certificates-into-javas-truststore-from-a-browser-a35e49a806dc

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to have to have any certificate (whether it's the server's, or a certificate authority that can validate the server's) stored locally? Effectively, you want to trust any server to which you connect, and not use TLS protocol to authenticate that it is the legitimate service?

Comment: Currently using Java 8.

Comment: @erikson - No, I'm not trying to bypass the process, just wondering if there was a way to do without having to store in a keystore.

Comment: Let start at the beginning. You've received an error (basically) saying the certificate the peer presented cannot be verified. Do you think that's a mistake? Why do you think it's a mistake and not, say, an attempted man-in-the-middle (MiTM) attack?